# send file with socket

Tags: c, sockets

What is wrong in this code (C - Linux)?

I want to receive a file from a server and as soon as I have a byte I send immediately this bytes. But It doesn't work. It's important.

```
int Recv_File(int server,int client,char *buffer_ricezione,size_t dimensione_file){

    ssize_t nwritten,nread;
    size_t n;
    char c;

    for (n=1; n<dimensione_file; n++) {
        nread = recv(server,&c,1,0);
        if (nread == 1) {
            nwritten = send(client,&c,1,0);
        }else{
            return -1; // chiudo connessione con il client
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should bufferize, so call `recv` with a buffer of several kilobytes, and you should use a multiplexing syscall like `poll`. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: Do you mean it isn't transmitted immediately?  TCP has its own algorithms for how it decides how to put bytes in a packet.  If this is the case you need to look at your tcp options.

Comment: Turning off Nagle's algorithm (via setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY)) would avoid the 200mS delay in sending, but it would perform very poorly if the program sends a single byte at a time, since each byte would go into its own separate network packet.  So if you turn off Nagle's, be sure to modify the function to send more than one byte per send() call!  (Ideal per-call size would be equal to or slightly less than the network's MTU size; i.e. 1384 bytes for Ethernet)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `n` should start with 0

```
for (n=0; n<dimensione_file; n++) {
    nread = recv(server,&c,1,0);
    if (nread == 1) {
        nwritten = send(client,&c,1,0);
    }else{
        return -1; // chiudo connessione con il client
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way, also the buffer_ricezione will be filled with the transmitted data.
Reading one byte and sending one byte at a time is not good and a lot of wasted resources.
Your code won't put anything in the reception's buffer which suppose to hold the transfered data.

```
 int Recv_File(int server,int client,char *buffer_ricezione,size_t dimensione_file){
 // This code assumes that buffer_recezione has been allocated at least dimensione_file

     ssize_t nwritten,nread;
     size_t n;
     // char c;
     size_t bLeft=dimensione_file;

     while (bLeft > 0)
     {
         nread = recv(server, buffer_ricezione, bLeft, 0);
         if (nread > 0) {
             if ((nwritten = send(client, buffer_ricezione, nread, 0)) != nread)
             {
                  return -1; // impossible to send to the socket, quit
             }
             bLeft -=nread;
             buffer_ricezione += nread;
         }else{
             return -1; // chiudo connessione con il client
         }
     }
     return 1;
 }
```